# Is the Spring Integration project inactive?

Tags: spring-integration

I'm looking into Spring Integration but the last bibliography I see on the subject is from 2012. It seems as if the project is dead. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What leads you to that conclusion? (I'd like to try to fix it if I can).

The project is very active; see the [github graphs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/graphs/commit-activity).

You can also see [the activity here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-integration).

Start with [the project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/).

Comment: OK, I can see development is active on GitHub and on the Spring project page, but bibliography has stopped in 2012. Do you know if a new book is coming out? It would be nice for instance to have documentation around the new functionality and especially Spring boot integration

Comment: Writing a good book takes a lot of effort for, unfortunately, very little reward. The project maintains a [comprehensive reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/); there are many [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) and [getting started guides](https://spring.io/guides) - we have a couple more integration guides in the works. Also see the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) for more documentation.

Comment: There is very little to no samples for java based implementation, now a days nobody is using xml based configuration and all the examples are either in xml or java DSL. Why the team is not updating the xml based examples to java based. Xml is so confusing and frustrating to find a solution.

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with the question. We just don't have enough hands to support samples on a decent level while we are pursuing the current market trends peeling new features and deprecating outdated. You can find also this recently started project as a samples repo: https://github.com/artembilan/microservices-patterns-spring-integration. There is no point to concentrate on a pure Java configuration since it is a bit cumbersome. It is not just a simple bean definition. That's why we have an XML, Java and other high-level DSLs.